# Get cell value where column value equals row/column value in second sheet

Tags: excel

I have two sheets:

Sheet 1:

```
Callsign  |  Dep ICAO  |  Arr ICAO  | Route
SWA215       KBUR         KOAK
AAL258       KLAS         KLAX
```

Sheet 2:

```
DEP ->  | KLAX          | KBUR        | KLAS        | KSAN
KSFO    | some route1   some route4   some route7   some route10
KOAK    | some route2   some route5   some route8   some route11
KLAX    | some route3   some route6   some route9   some route12
ARR ^
```

Basically I need to find the route value in `Sheet 2` where the DEP & ARR column equals the `Dep ICAO` and `Arr ICAO` in `Sheet 1`.

So for example, in sheet one, the route value for SWA215 should return `some route5`. The route value for AAL258 should return `some route9`.

I've tried messing with VLOOKUP but I wasn't sure how to incorporate two different sheets. Here's what I had for the function:

`=VLOOKUP(B2:C2,Sheet 2!A1:Q18,Sheet 2!B2:E4)` but it returned `#VALUE!` error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need INDEX with two MATCH(Two Way Lookup).
Try the below example:

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!C3:E6,MATCH(Sheet1!D4,Sheet2!B3:B6,0),MATCH(Sheet1!C4,Sheet2!C2:E2,0))
```

Where Sheet2!C3:E6 is the route range(data you need). The first MATCH matches the arr in arr col and MATCH 2 matches the dep in dep row. In this example formula should be placed in sheet1 cell E4

Comment: Works perfectly...and great formulas to know and use in the future. Thanks!